# Multilanguage URLs

Tags: permalinks, filters, url-rewriting, multi-language, home-url

I am trying to achieve multilanguage behaviour for my website. I'm very close but not quite there and feel like I'm running in circles. That's why I decide to ask for your help.

I'd like to use URLs like `mysite.com/fr/some_page` to take me to what would normally be `mysite.com/some_page` which would then be displayed in French.

I've actually gotten this to work by enabling pretty permalinks and using a rewrite rule:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z])/(.+)', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[2]&lang=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

and adding the `lang` variable to `query_vars`:

```
function add_query_vars( $vars )
{
    $vars[] = 'lang';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars' );
```

But this doesn't work on the home page. In fact, the entire `$wp_query->query_vars` is made of empty values. Not even passing the query parameter in the URL works: `mysite.com/?lang=fr` (as I read somewhere this is because it tries to match a post when it sees a `?`)

I've even tried to add a new rewrite rule, specifically for the home page:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z])/?$', 'index.php?pagename=home_slug&lang=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

To no avail.

Does anyone know how I can do this? If not, my only option is to painstakingly try to follow through the code to understand how wordpress handles the urls, but I'm afraid it won't be an easy task.

Forgot to mention that I'm specifically interested in pages not posts. My site is made of pages.

Comment: So weird! I've changed the rewrite rule for the home page to `add_rewrite_rule('^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z])/?$', 'index.php?pagename=home_slug&cpage=1&lang=$matches[1]', 'top');`
 and now it works!!! I've just added `cpage` to the `query_vars`! It doesn't seem to work with other variables.

Comment: You should think about a multilingual concept via WP Multisite to get easier different domains and lot of more benefits. It give also plugins to work inside the Multisite with benefits, like relationship between the posts in different languages.

Comment: My site is very small to consider any thorough approach. That is why I started by making my own plugin. I was counting on more support from wordpress to implement this.

I had looked first at Polylang as a plugin but I did not like its approach of having separate pages/posts per language.

What I ended up doing, until I find better approaches, is intercepting URLs very early and filtering them before wordpress gets a hold of them. It is good enough for now. It's what I would do if I were to make the website without wordpress.

Comment: I wish wordpress allowed me to define the rules for URLs for everything, including pages, posts and other entities and include my custom tags (like %lang%) that change dynamically (for every reload). At some point I thought I'd found that with rewrite rules but they don't seem to work like I hoped.